# Converting very short "motionless" video frames to single, better-resolved, images

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, video-compression, superresolution, image-restoration

I made a mistake with my newly bought compact camera, before a trip to Japan. Instead of taking single pictures, I ended up with a few short "MP4" video files (1 second, 2-3 frames). I could "easily enough" extract individual frames with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), using help from:

- [Extract all video frames as images with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786669/extract-all-video-frames-as-images-with-ffmpeg/34786929)
- [Extract images frame by frame from a video file using FFMPEG](https://www.bugcodemaster.com/article/extract-images-frame-frame-video-file-using-ffmpeg)
- [Fastest way to extract frames using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957412/fastest-way-to-extract-frames-using-ffmpeg)
- [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from an H264 video file with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/7453794) [NOT TRIED YET]

I am unsatisfied with the quality of some frames, and as there is very little motion, I would like to restore or recreate a superresolution image from those two-three frames only, using the motion vector.

I would appreciate suggestions, software experience, etc. For readers interested in trying algorithms, I provided in the 22 MB file [StackExchange-AVI2JPG.zip](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/Data/MP42JPG/StackExchange-AVI2JPG.zip) two examples with media information (obtained with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/fr/MediaInfo)) and camera reference (to avoid unwanted advertizing). One leaving Osaka, with a relatively nicely flat image:

[image: Leaving Osaka in the bus]

the other from Nara, Todai-Ji:

[image: Nara, Todai-Ji]

where the wire fence is sharper, hence the individual frame quality is poorer. I enjoyed my trip, and would be glad to share crisper images of the first day ([a view on the Fuji in the early for the finest eyes](https://twitter.com/laurentduval/status/1104836475357671426)).

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/10225403/4386900 ?

Comment: None, thanks for the hint. I'm going to check and add it

Comment: Does the camera have Video Stabilization feature? Is it digital or mechanical? Does it have any information about the motion sensors?

Comment: Yes is does. I think it was set, but I bought the camera just before the trip, and I did not read the manual soon enough. It is not appropriate to advertize, but let's say it is called TZOO (not O, but zeroes) by p*n*s*n*c

Comment: @LaurentDuval, Probably better extract frames as a `PNG` (Or just arrays if using `MATLAB` for example) and then try Multiple Image Super Resolution.

Comment: @LaurentDuval What did you end up doing? Anything or just squint?